# Mongo DB and NodeJS partial text matching with encrypted column

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, encryption

I'm creating a chat application where I am encrypting all the messages sent and storing it in MongoDB. When I want to send the message history back to client, I would paginate and decrypt and send the client back messages. Now I need to add a feature to search the message contents and retrieve a few messages before and after that.

```
var messageData = {
    sender_id:"abcd",
    reciever_id: "efgh",
    message: encrypt("Hello world") //Function written using crypto in node.
}

db.collection("messsages").insertOne(messageData, { w: 1 }, function (
              err,
              result
            ) {
              if (err) throw err;
              client.close();

              return res.status(200).json({
                status: "SUCCESS",
                message: "Message Sent",
              });
            });
```

A similar kind of thing happens on decryption. How exactly do I search the encrypted messages without decrypting every single one of them? I know for a fact that this is possible in web since Facebook Messenger does this. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: What does facebook messenger do exactly?

Comment: @D.SM I'm sure messenger does not store messages in the backend as plain text, yet they managed to provide a search feature for messages.

Comment: " I know for a fact that this is possible in web since Facebook Messenger does this" != " I'm sure messenger does not store messages in the backend as plain text".

Answer (score 0):

Unless your encryption is implemented in such a way that encrypt('foo') and encrypt('bar') are substrings of encrypt('foo bar'), you need to have the decrypted message contents for the search to work.